# Spring Security Oauth2 JWT works for .properties but no for .yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, properties-file

I am using SpringBoot and I encoutered pretty weird problem. I have resource server and it works fine with application.properties, but when I tried to migrate .properties to .yml 
I am getting UNATHORIZED error, when I send request with JWT token to one of my Controllers.

application.yml

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      id: ouath2_id
```

application.properties

```
security.oauth2.resource.id=oauth2_id
```

ResourceConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${security.oauth2.resource.id}")
    private String resourceId;

    private String publicKey = "xxx";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        System.out.println("RESORCEID: " + resourceId); //IT IS LOADING CORRECTLY
        resources
                .resourceId(resourceId)
                .tokenServices(tokenServices())
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
        .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthEntryPoint())
        .accessDeniedHandler(customDeniedHandler());
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthEntryPoint(){
        return new AuthFailureHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandler customDeniedHandler(){
        return new AccessDeniedHandlerImpl();
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .anonymous().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
    }


    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }


    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);
        return converter;
    }
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenEnhancer(accessTokenConverter());
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
}
```

I checked, and the only property which I load form poperties is resourceId and It's getting desired value.

So the only difference is .yml instead .properties

I have no clue what is the problem.